# Spark 2.3: Flatten Array of Array of Structs, and create new columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe with a column `ids` that looks like

```
ids
WrappedArray(WrappedArray([item1,micro], [item3, mini]), WrappedArray([item2,macro]))
WrappedArray(WrappedArray([item1,micro]), WrappedArray([item5,micro], [item6,macro]))
```

where the exact type of the column is

```
StructField(ids,ArrayType(ArrayType(StructType(StructField(identifier,StringType,true), StructField(identifierType,StringType,true)),true),true),true)
```

I want to create two new columns, one holding the value of all of the distinct `identifier` in the struct, and another column holding the max observed `identifierType` for that row (if there are ties, then return all the ties).

So in our example, I would like the output to be

```
list_of_identifiers, most_frequent_type
Array(item1, item2, item3), [micro, mini, macro]
Array(item1, item5, item6), [micro]
```

To achieve this, the first step I need to do is flatten the `ids` column to something like

```
ids
WrappedArray([item1,micro], [item3, mini], [item2,macro])
WrappedArray([item1,micro], [item5,micro], [item6,macro])
```

but I cannot figure out the way to do this.

Here is sample input table

```
val arrayStructData = Seq(
  Row(List(List(Row("item1", "micro"),Row("item3", "mini")), List(Row("item2", "macro")))),
  Row(List(List(Row("item1", "micro")), List(Row("item5", "micro"), Row("item6", "macro"))))
)

val arrayStructSchema = new StructType()
  .add("ids", ArrayType(ArrayType(new StructType()
    .add("identifier",StringType)
    .add("identifierType",StringType))))

val df = spark.createDataFrame(spark.sparkContext
  .parallelize(arrayStructData),arrayStructSchema)
```

Comment: Could you provide some dummy data from the df?

Comment: Kindly include dummy data and schema of your dataframe.

Comment: @Niko I have updated the post.

Comment: which Spark version are you using?